# Missing notification of condition variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++14

In the following code I've a worker thread which is going to have one major state - Started. Started isn't the thread launch state but the state when a blocking call finally returns which I've replaced with a random delay and comment.

What I'm trying here is to first launch the worker thread asap, block on it's blocking call while keeping `started = false` till it doesn't returns. As soon as it returns, I'll put `started = true` and notify `main` thread's infinite loop to launch another thread and wait again. The previous worker thread can resume doing its work now. And then repeat this process. *The launch of new thread must wait for the START state of previous thread.*

But in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156908/c-condition-variable-notification-not-working-as-expected), someone mentioned this -

> If cv.notify_one is called before cv.wait is running the notification
>   will be missed. In the presented code it most probably will.

***For now I tried to manually test it in various ways possible but couldn't get an error and everything is working as I thought. So I want to know in what situation will it actually miss it, anyway to make it reproducible, and how to actually solve it if it is a problem?***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <random>

std::mt19937_64 eng{std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist{100, 2000};

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool started = false;
std::atomic<int> count(0);

void worker_thread()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    int local_cnt = count++;

    // some blocking call represented by random delay
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{dist(eng)});
    std::cerr << "Enter Accept: " << local_cnt << "\n";

    started = true;
    lk.unlock();
    cv.notify_one(); // notify to launch other threads

    // complete other work here
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{dist(eng) + 2000});
    std::cerr << "Exit Accept: " << local_cnt << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    while(1){
        std::thread(worker_thread).detach();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{return started;});
        started = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case, it's OK to lose the notification that happened before `wait` is called. In that case, by the time `wait` is called, `started` is already set to `true`, so `wait` will just check it and return immediately.